# Issue Pushing values in to objects Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Have some issue with push the values in to the javascript array object. Please any one give me the perfect solution

```
Class code : 

    var myfuns = ( function(undefined) {

    var myarr ={};


    function _add(arrayparam){
        if (myarr.current == undefined) { 
            myarr.current = [];
            myarr.current.push(options.current_info);
        }else{

        }
    }
    function _getList() {
            return $.extend(true, {}, myarr);
    }
        return {
        add : _add,
        getList : _getList
    }   

}());
```

Here am calling and manage the values and keys

```
function setmydetails(){

    var my_param = {
            current_info : {
                pg : '#tset',
                no : 12,
                name : "john",
                row : 0,
            },

            userprofile : [],
            class : [],
            marks : [],
            games : []
        };

    myfuns.add(my_param);
}
```

Now i got the array

```
myfuns.getList()  // GOT proper array what i passed in my_param
```

**Question :** How to modify the existing values from any one of the Inner array from the myarr Obj

Ex: Once First array created later have to modify some from "myarr.current" = > Change current_info.row to 2222

Similar i have to add some array  in to  " myarr.class " etc

Comment: is it `myfunc._add(...)` or ?

Comment: How does that code even work? You're not returning _anything_ to `myfuns`. I don't believe you're getting any array at all.

Comment: **first thing** you cant access the private function of class outside the class **myfuns.getList()** here **getList** is private

Comment: you can access through `... return {add:_add, ...}` inside of your class

Comment: here is no return statement in the quetion

Comment: Now i added that.. Missed in last post.. But my question is how to modify .. and add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to say **try** this one **not tested**

```
function _add(arrayparam){
    if (myarr.current == undefined) { 
        myarr.current = [];
        myarr.current.push(options.current_info);
    }else{
        $.extend( myarr.current, arrayparam);
    }
}
```

**proper source :**  https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/